# Data Fetch Using Php CUrl and Regular Expressions

Tags: php, regex, curl

I wish to fetch information from one webpage using php curl, I am filtering data using php regular expression to match tag, but not working.

here is webpage [click here](http://vikramshopping.com/reallife-3in1-printscriptcopy-5)

here is my php code

```
if(preg_match('/<div class="price-gruop"><span class="text-price">Price:<\/span>(.*?)<\/div>/', get_page($url),$matches2))
        {
       $matches2[1] = strtolower($matches2[1]);
       $data['price']=$matches2[1];

        }

function get_page($url){
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
//curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PROXY, $proxy);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0); // return headers 0 no 1 yes
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true); // return page 1:yes
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 200); // http request timeout 20 seconds
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true); // Follow redirects, need this if the url changes
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS, 2); //if http server gives redirection responce
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT,
    "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US; rv:1.8.1.7) Gecko/20070914 Firefox/2.0.0.7");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, "cookies.txt"); // cookies storage / here the changes have been made
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, "cookies.txt");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false); // false for https
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_ENCODING, "gzip"); // the page encoding

$data = curl_exec($ch); // execute the http request
curl_close($ch); // close the connection
return $data;
}
```

I am getting string null value. please tell me how to get value in between tags.

Comment: check out [xpath](http://php.net/manual/en/class.domxpath.php). Much better suited to parsing html if there are lots of elements you are scraping

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using **`PHP DOM`** download `simple_html_dom.php` from here [link](http://sourceforge.net/projects/simplehtmldom/files/)

```
$url = "http://vikramshopping.com/reallife-3in1-printscriptcopy-5";
// Include the library
include('simple_html_dom.php');

// Retrieve the DOM from a given URL
$html = file_get_html($url);
```

**it is what you need that I understand**

```
// Find all DIV tags that have a class of "price-gruop" 
foreach($html->find('div.price-gruop') as $e) {
    echo $e->outertext . '<br>';
}
```

OR with **preg_match**

```
$html = '<div class="price-gruop">
                            <span class="text-price">Price:</span>
                                                        INR135.00                                                   </div>';
if(preg_match('/<div class="price-gruop">\s*<span class="text-price">\s*Price:\s*<\/span>\s*(.*)\s*<\/div>/', $html,$matches))
echo '<pre>';print_r("Price: ".$matches[1]);echo '</pre>';
```

[Demo with preg_match](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/2e0f24fe49311765d76436481761e60b6518e128)

also you can use other examples from below

```
// Find all "A" tags and print their HREFs
foreach($html->find('a') as $e)
    echo $e->href . '<br>';

// Retrieve all images and print their SRCs
foreach($html->find('img') as $e)
    echo $e->src . '<br>';

// Find all images, print their text with the "<>" included
foreach($html->find('img') as $e)
    echo $e->outertext . '<br>';

// Find the DIV tag with an id of "myId"
foreach($html->find('div#myId') as $e)
    echo $e->innertext . '<br>';

// Find all SPAN tags that have a class of "myClass"
foreach($html->find('div.myClass') as $e)
    echo $e->outertext . '<br>';

// Find all TD tags with "align=center"
foreach($html->find('td[align=center]') as $e)
    echo $e->innertext . '<br>';

// Extract all text from a given cell
echo $html->find('td[align="center"]', 1)->plaintext.'<br><hr>';
```

Comment: Thank You for your Help, But I need to to with regular expression.

Comment: Thank You Noman. It is working. Superb.