# How to extract data from html using PHP

Tags: php

I am trying to get data(like job vacancy) from page like http://www.quest.edu.pk/jobs/.I dont know how to get this.can anyone help me in doing this.
Thanku in advance.

Comment: preg_match or curl or use this link http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/

Comment: @SunilPachlangia Please explain how `preg_match` can do this on it's own?

Comment: my answer will help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30068985/data-fetch-using-php-curl-and-regular-expresions/30069330#30069330

Answer (score -1):

php has inbuilt function `file_get_contents` to extract complete html source of webpage - like below:

```
$html=file_get_contents("http://www.quest.edu.pk/jobs/")
```

But its not recommended because we can not set timeout parameter in function. So instead of this you can use curl library and preg_match as suggested by @Sunil Pachlangia & @Noman.

you can refer this [Link](http://99webtools.com/blog/extract-website-data-using-php/) for more information.